# Creating 'summary' column from detail table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application that has several `stores`, and each store has several records in `store_hours`.

The `store_hours` table looks like this:

```
store_id [int]
day [varchar(20)]
opening_time [varchar(20)]
closing_time [varchar(20)]
```

and the records for one store may look like this:

```
301, 'Monday', '7am', '8:30pm'
301, 'Tuesday', '7am', '8:30pm'
301, 'Wednesday', '7am', '8:30pm'
301, 'Thursday', '7am', '8:30pm'
301, 'Friday', '7am', '10pm'
301, 'Saturday', 'closed,' 'closed'
301, 'Sunday', 'closed,' 'closed'
```

We're trying to make an "hours summary" column on the store table.  The above query would result in something like 'M: 7am-8:30pm, T: 7am-8:30pm, W: 7am-8:30pm, T: 7am-8:30pm, F: 7am-8:30pm, S: closed, S: closed'

I'm populating it by running a query similar to this:

```
UPDATE s
SET hours_summary = 
'M: ' + (SELECT TOP 1 ch.opening_time FROM store_hours ch WHERE c.id = ch.store AND [day] = 'Monday') + '-' + (SELECT TOP 1 ch.closing_time FROM store_hours ch WHERE c.id = ch.store AND [day] = 'Monday') + ', ' +
'T: ' + (SELECT TOP 1 ch.opening_time FROM store_hours ch WHERE c.id = ch.store AND [day] = 'Tuesday') + '-' + (SELECT TOP 1 ch.closing_time FROM store_hours ch WHERE c.id = ch.store AND [day] = 'Tuesday') + ', '
    (etc, for the other five days)
FROM stores s
```

Now, this will work (more or less), but I have a couple questions.

1. This is ugly, in my opinion, and seems to have a lot of repetion.  Is there anyway you can think of to improve it?
2. For some records, if the store is closed, there is no record at all in the store_hours table.  I haven't come up with a good way to handle this.  Suggestions?

**EDIT**

Several people have recommended using a pivot table.  I see how I can get the opening *or* closing time in there, but I don't see how I can do both, and I don't see how I can summarize it into one query.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT centre, [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday]
FROM (SELECT centre, [day], opening_time FROM centre_hours) AS p
PIVOT (MAX(opening_time) FOR [day] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday])) AS pt
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

For those of you from the future wondering if/how I got around this, I ended up creating two separate pivot tables, then INSERTing the results of the first table, and UPDATEing with the results from the second.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008, I hardly recommend you would use the `TIME` datatype for your `opening_time` and `closing_time` columns

Comment: Pivot is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you. No update or insert. The same table as you original post

```
DECLARE @store_hours TABLE
(
    store_id int,
    [day] varchar(20),
    opening_time varchar(20),
    closing_time varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @store_hours(store_id,[day],opening_time,closing_time)VALUES(301, 'Monday', '7am', '8:30pm')
INSERT INTO @store_hours(store_id,[day],opening_time,closing_time)VALUES(301, 'Tuesday', '7am', '8:30pm')
INSERT INTO @store_hours(store_id,[day],opening_time,closing_time)VALUES(301, 'Wednesday', '7am', '8:30pm')
INSERT INTO @store_hours(store_id,[day],opening_time,closing_time)VALUES(301, 'Thursday', '7am', '8:30pm')
INSERT INTO @store_hours(store_id,[day],opening_time,closing_time)VALUES(301, 'Friday', '7am', '10pm')
INSERT INTO @store_hours(store_id,[day],opening_time,closing_time)VALUES(301, 'Saturday', 'closed', 'closed')
INSERT INTO @store_hours(store_id,[day],opening_time,closing_time)VALUES(301, 'Sunday', 'closed' ,'closed')

SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        [day], 
        opening_time+'-'+closing_time AS Times
    FROM @store_hours AS store_hours
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Times)
        FOR [day] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday],[Sunday])
    )AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: That is perfect! (Except for you missed Thursday in your pivot... But I won't judge you too harshly for that!)  Thanks!

Comment: Okey sorry about that. Update the solution for that. Did the suggestion quite fast..

Comment: Nice, I had a different schema in mind - I've always hated pivoting :) great job!

Comment: Thanks mate. I think a pivot is a excellent piece of syntax in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually pivot the data and make the column headings display the days with the times.
See pivot help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: With the way your data is structured this could get ugly, maybe what you have is not so bad.  I usually pivot my front end and use the backend just to snatch the data.  Even pivot in this case could be ugly...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to judge whether the store_hours schema is right in this scenario without knowing more. You could of designed the schema for the opening hours a bit differently - normally thought you would be right to have a row per day - that is kind of the default design pattern.

This is one of those fixed scenarios that you could choose to pivot the columns in the schema to make life a bit easier. (Depeding what else uses this though, could make it harder, so there is a caveat here of depends on your usages.)

```
store_id [int] 
week_begin_dt [datetime]
mon_opening_time [varchar(20)] 
mon_closing_time [varchar(20)] 
tue_opening_time [varchar(20)] 
tue_closing_time [varchar(20)] 
...
sun_opening_time [varchar(20)] 
sun_closing_time [varchar(20)]
```

Regardless of solution, I would also include an effective beginning date for the store hours, since over time they will change so you want to potentially be able to time phase the data. This will let you account for future store hours and not just the current hours for the current week. (Holidays and peak periods will change the store hours normally.)